# How to parse this message ! About Exception message

Tags: java

message = ""

> Validation failed for classes [com.PointsSystem.entity.Membership]
> during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default,
> ]\nList of constraint
> violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='请输入正确的手机号(11位)',
> propertyPath=cellPhone, rootBeanClass=class
> com.PointsSystem.entity.Membership,
> messageTemplate='请输入正确的手机号(11位)'}\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='lastName
> 不能为空', propertyPath=lastName, rootBeanClass=class
> com.PointsSystem.entity.Membership, messageTemplate='lastName
> 不能为空'}\n]

""

I do not want to print this message on my web app, I need to get the key word "interpolatedMessage" which contains Chinese characters. How can I do that? This message was get when i use e.getMessage, e ment a Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to catch or write a handler for ConstraintViolationException.

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> handleConstraintViolation(final ConstraintViolationException exception,
            final WebRequest request) {
        final List<String> errors = exception.getConstraintViolations()
                .parallelStream()
                .map(violation -> violation
                      .getInvalidValue() + " : " + violation.getMessage())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    }
```

Or in catch block.

```
try {
} catch() {
   final List<String> errors = exception.getConstraintViolations()
                    .parallelStream()
                    .map(violation -> violation
                          .getInvalidValue() + " : " + violation.getMessage())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: yes，i have do that!!! , I havent seen this solve way before ,it seem like a currect answer hhh

Comment: thanks guys! i just copy your code! and it work,  Learned something！！